# Underscore.js unique values and counts of a property : alongwith another property.: 2 levels

Tags: underscore.js

I am new to Underscore.js

Suppose I have this array of objects :

```
[
    { couponid: 500, locationid: 10 },
    { couponid: 600, locationid: 15 }, 
    { couponid: 500, locationid: 10 }, 
    { couponid: 500, locationid: 20 } 
]
```

I got unique couponids(500,600) along with counts for each couponid, using :

```
_.countBy(result, "couponid")
```

wherein result is the array.

Can anyone please tell, now how can i get, for each unique couponid, how many unique location ids( alongwith the locationids ) ? ie in the above couponid 500 would have count 2, and couponid 600 would have count 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly I think this will do what you want:

```
var result = _.chain(data)
    .groupBy('couponid')
    .mapObject( group => _.countBy(group, 'locationid'))
    .value()
```

First we group by the `couponid` and then map that object to count each `locationid` within that group.

This will result in an object that looks like this:

```
{
    500: {
       10: 2,
       20: 1
    },

    600: {
       15: 1
    }   
}
```

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for. Earlier, with _.countBy(result, "couponid"), I was getting the Unique Coupon IDs with their counts. (This is generating data for Highcharts chart) Now for Location-wise drill down I needed this. Anyone reading this, the earlier line  _.countBy(result, "couponid") was also answered by Gruff, on another StackOverflow Question.